# How does one create an object based on the precedence of another object's key order?

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value, creation

I have an object like this -

```
const obj = {
    'veh1': 'Car',
    'veh2': 'Bicycle',
    'veh3': 'Truck',
    'wheels1': '4',
    'wheels2': '2',
    'wheels3': '8'
}
```

I want an **object** which have entries mapped like-
**veh1 to wheels1**, **veh2 to wheels2**, **veh3 to wheels3 and so on**
The resultant object should be like this-

```
const result = {
    'Car': '4',
    'Bicycle': '2',
    'Truck': '8'
}
```

I know, we can do it directly like this -

```
{
   [obj.veh1]: obj.wheels1,
   [obj.veh2]: obj.wheels2,
   [obj.veh3]: obj.wheels3
}
```

But what will be the better way? The number of entries can be any number 'n'.

How can I attain this through javascript?

Comment: Loop through all object keys that start with `veh` and then find the matching `wheel` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create entries (key value pairs) from the provided object.
2. Sort the entries by each of an entry's key.
3. Finally create a new objects from the upper (or left) as well the lower (or right) half of the before sorted entries.

```js
function localeCompare(a, b) {
  return (a.localeCompare && b.localeCompare
    && a.localeCompare(b))
    || (((a < b) && -1) || ((a > b) && 1) || 0);
}

function compareEntriesByKey(entryA, entryB) {
  return localeCompare(entryA[0], entryB[0]);
}

function createKeyValuePairFromSortedEntryHalfs(obj, $, idx, entries) {
  if (((idx + 1) % 2) === 0) {
 
    const keyIdx = ((idx - 1) / 2);
    const valueIdx = (keyIdx + Math.floor(entries.length / 2));

    const key = entries[keyIdx][1];
    const value = entries[valueIdx][1];

    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}


const obj = {
  'wheels3': '8',
  'veh3': 'Truck',
  'wheels1': '4',
  'veh1': 'Car',
  'wheels2': '2',
  'veh2': 'Bicycle',
}
const result = Object
  // (1) create entries (key value pairs) from the provided object.
  .entries(obj)
  // (2) sort the entries by each of an entry's key.
  .sort(compareEntriesByKey)
  // (3) finally create a new objects from the upper (or left) as
  //     well the lower (or right) half of the before sorted entries.
  .reduce(createKeyValuePairFromSortedEntryHalfs, {});

console.log('result :', result);

console.log('obj', obj);
console.log(
  'Object.entries(obj).sort(compareEntriesByKey)',
  Object.entries(obj).sort(compareEntriesByKey)
);

console.log(
  'proof of being a generic approach...', `
  Object.entries({
    'foo-biz': 'biz',
    'x': 111,
    'foo-baz': 'baz',
    'y': 222,
    'foo-bar': 'bar',
    'z': 333,
  }).sort(
    compareEntriesByKey
  ).reduce(
    createKeyValuePairFromSortedEntryHalfs,
    {}
  ) =>`, Object.entries({
    'foo-biz': 'biz',
    'x': 111,
    'foo-baz': 'baz',
    'y': 222,
    'foo-bar': 'bar',
    'z': 333,
  }).sort(
    compareEntriesByKey
  ).reduce(
    createKeyValuePairFromSortedEntryHalfs,
    {}
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const vehicles = {};
const wheels = {};
const result = {};

for (key in obj) {
  if (key.startsWith("veh")) {
    const id = key.replace("veh", "");
    vehicles[id] = obj[key];
    if (wheels.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      result[vehicles[id]] = wheels[id];
    }
  } else if (key.startsWith("wheels")) {
    const id = key.replace("wheels", "");
    wheels[id] = obj[key];
    if (vehicles.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      result[vehicles[id]] = wheels[id];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach only works for keys that start with either `veh` or `wheels`. For it has to be adopted to any changes of an object's key pattern, it is not a generic one.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I assumed the question was asking for this specific example and not a generic one. This approach has a 1-pass, linear running time whereas your solution requires 2 passes and sorting. Maybe OP can clarify their use case.

Comment: ... understood and upvoted. BTW your approach is much more robust than the one of *ZaO Lover* because the latter does rely on an exact key order.

Answer (score -1):

```
const obj = {
  'veh1': 'Car',
  'veh2': 'Bicycle',
  'veh3': 'Truck',
  'wheels1': '4',
  'wheels2': '2',
  'wheels3': '8'
}

let res = {};
let keys = Object.keys(obj);
let i;
for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++) {
  if(keys[i].slice(0, 3) === 'veh') {
    res[obj[keys[i]]] = obj[`wheels${keys[i].slice(3)}`];
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: One can not rely on the key order, especially if the key value pairs will not be provided in such an ideal way like with the OP's code example. A generic approach, which finally creates the new key value pairs, also does not need to make any assumptions about any of the original object's keys as done within your example.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. It does the same thing but less lines. One question: why do you need to cast to an int?